# c#: write to log file instead of Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, io, streamwriter, file-writing, console.writeline

I like how Console.Writeline can be called from any part of a program, and it simply adds to the text already there.  Is there a way to have that same ease but with writing to a text file instead?

```
public int my_function(int A, int B)
{
   string this_line = string.format("total value: {0}", A+B);
   Console.Writeline(this_string) 
}
```

My solution so far is below.  It works fine, but I feel there must be a better way.  Maybe some way to have a global StreamWriter object I can access in all functions without passing it to them?

```
public int my_function(int A, int B)
{
   string this_line = string.format("total value: {0}", A+B);
   File.AppendAllText(logfile_path, this_line); 
}
```

Comment: Beware of multi-threading issues.

Comment: You should use a logging framework.

Comment: Redirection? When calling the raoutine in a command line add `>> FileToRedirect.txt` `MyRoutine.exe >> c:\MyFile.txt` or even `MyRoutine.exe >> c:\Log.txt 2>> c:\Errors.txt` (redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` into different files)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a logging framework such as log4net.

https://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Beginners tutorial here

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial

log4net allows you to log to file, database, console and custom 'appenders'.

Comment: Serilog is way better imo

Comment: Thanks, not seen that. Will have a look

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using NLog:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Examples

```
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Target = new FileTarget("path to your log file");
string this_line = string.format("total value: {0}", A+B);
logger.Info(this_line);
```

or you can use log4net